# AWS Amplify data specific authorization

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, authorization, aws-amplify

I have a model called "type User" and a model "type Group"

```
type User
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }])
  {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    age: Int
    owner: ID!
  }
```

Here my group model:

```
type Group
   @model
   @auth(rules: [{
        allow: owner
        ownerField: "adminIds"
        operations: [create, read, update]
      }
      { allow: owner, ownerField: "userIds", operations: [create, read] }
      ])
    {
      userIds: []
      adminIds: []     
    }
```

Now how do i set up an authorization so that the the admin users are able to read the `User` even if they are not the owner?

From my point of knowledge the problem is if you want to use a lambda for authorization and want to fetch an user you can easy check if you are the owner, but you cannot check a other Table in this case `Group` because you dont have the information?